# Test coverage for Kotlin Multiplatform project(KMM)

Tags: android, android-testing, kotlin-multiplatform, test-coverage, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have one project(android and iOS) where I am sharing the common code inside shared folder. I have written both unit tests under commonTest(unit-test) folder as well as Instrumentation test inside androidTest(instrumentation test) folder. It works well when I run individual test. But I want to see the coverage also. While I can do this "run with test coverage" for commonTest but it's not available for androidTest. Any tool that will be helpful here. I tried searching and tried few stuffs with jacoco and kover but could not help.